# When was the last Rajasuya yajna conducted?

Tags: yajna, sacrifice

Many kings such as Yudhishthira and Bharata conducted Rajasuya yajna. Who was the last king to conduct the Rajasuya yagna?

Comment: In the texts, I think it's Yuddhishthira only, at least in Mahabharata. In some local scriptures there maybe others.